# Load xml only once

Tags: php, xml

I need to load xml file only once..
This is in a function

```
    static $xml = 0;
    if($xml == 0){
        $xml =  simplexml_load_file('themes/colors.xml');
    }
```

This should work? How i can test if file is loaded only once?

Comment: Log, print, giving feedback in some way when the file is loaded. So under the line where you load it (`simplexml_load_file`), put an echo or open a file to append a log message. For the default value I'd use `null` though. Depends on what `simplexml_load_file` could return. What you're doing is right, `static` should work here.

Comment: You can put your test code in a very large loop and compare the execution time against a single call to that code.

Comment: Print something every time you're about to call `simplexml_load_file`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function returns false on failure, so you can just check to see if `$xml === false` at some point after you call the function.

Why do you think it would load more than once? If the reason you think it may be loaded more than once has something to do with the rest of your code, you should extract the call to load the file into its own method/function.

Also, it would be a good idea to wrap the call to simplexml_load_file in an if statement that ensures that the file exists:

```
$filename = 'themes/colors.xml';
if(file_exists($filename)){
  $xml =  simplexml_load_file($filename);
}
```

If there is an error, you can call `libxml_get_errors` to determine the problem, as described here: [libxml_get_errors docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-get-errors.php)